# Jquery validation is working for all field excepting cvv field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var toValidate = jQuery("#fullname, #address, #city, #state,#zip,#phone,#country,#expireMM,#expireYY,#card_number,#cvv_number"),
                valid = false;
            toValidate.keyup(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
                    jQuery(this).data('valid', true);
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).data('valid', false);
                }
                toValidate.each(function () {
                    if (jQuery(this).data('valid') == true) {
                        valid = true;
                    } else {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                });
                if (valid === true) {
                    jQuery("#signInSubmit").prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    jQuery("#signInSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
```

Above jquery validation working for all field excepting cvv.when i submit form if all field blank button remain disabled after filling all fields button enable but this not working for cvv field if all fields blank and i fill cvv field form submit and disable attribute remove.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
toValidate.each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).data('valid') == true) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        valid = false;
    }
});
```

Here while checking all elements, `cvv` is the last element and as per the condition the value `valid` will be `true`. And because of it the your button is getting enabled.

You can do something like this :

```
var valid = true;
toValidate.each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).data('valid') == true && valid !== false) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        valid = false;
    }
});
```

improve the code as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much